Blank screen after building with electron-builder
I converted my React app into an Electron app so that I can run the application as a executable. I can run the application no problem in development, but when I build the app using electron-builder and try to run the executable, all that shows is a blank screen. Is this a common error that people run into if so how do I fix it? Also I am not using react-router-dom in my react project nor am I doing any routing to other pages, it is a single page application.
This is my main.js file in the public dir for electron
`
// main.js
// Modules to control application life and create native browser window
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const path = require('node:path')

const createWindow = () => {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    title: 'T.I.N.C.A.N.',
    frame: true,
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      worldSafeExecution: true,
      contextIsolation: true,
    }
  })

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  // mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')
  mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:3000')

  // Open the DevTools.
  // mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()

  app.on('activate', () => {
    // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
    // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
  })
})

// Quit when all windows are closed, except on macOS. There, it's common
// for applications and their menu bar to stay active until the user quits
// explicitly with Cmd + Q.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.`

And this is my package.json file
{
      "name": "chess",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "author": "Reece Cristea and Tim O'Shea",
      "description": "Chess AI Application",
      "main": "public/main.js",
      "dependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
        "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
        "concurrently": "^8.2.2",
        "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
        "wait-on": "^7.2.0",
        "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
        "yarn": "^1.22.22"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
        "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
        "concurrently": "^8.2.2",
        "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
        "electron": "^30.0.1",
        "electron-builder": "^24.13.3",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
        "wait-on": "^7.2.0",
        "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
        "yarn": "^1.22.22"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject",
        "electron-dev": "electron .",
        "electron:serve": "concurrently -k \"cross-env BROWSER=none yarn start \" \"yarn electron:start\" ",
        "electron:build": "yarn build && electron-builder -c.extraMetadata.main=build/main.js",
        "electron:start": "wait-on http://127.0.0.1:3000 && electron ."
      },
      "build": {
        "extends": null,
        "appId": "com.tincan.app",
        "files": [
          "dist/**/*",
          "build/**/*",
          "node_modules/**/*",
          "package.json",
          "public/**/*"
        ],
        "directories": {
          "buildResources": "assets"
        },
        "win": {
          "target": "NSIS"
        },
        "mac": {
          "target": "dmg"
        },
        "linux": {
          "target": [
            "snap",
            "AppImage",
            "deb"
          ]
        }
      },
      "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
          "react-app",
          "react-app/jest"
        ]
      },
      "browserslist": {
        "production": [
          ">0.2%",
          "not dead",
          "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
          "last 1 chrome version",
          "last 1 firefox version",
          "last 1 safari version"
        ]
      }
    }


why are your devDependencies the same as your dependencies?

You might also want to look into Electron Fiddle.

I am somewhat new to React and web development so I don't really know which dependencies I need where, I received an error saying electron and electron-builder can't be in the dependencies if I want to build it so I just copy pasted everything into devDependencies and removed electron and electron-builder from dependencies.

If you build your React App, the builder will build static files in a directory like "build".
If you run it in dev, it will launch a server on localhost.
So, if you run your dev script, a Server on localhost will run with your React app and you calling it in your main.js like:
mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:3000')
if you build your electron app, the build script will be run and adds the react static files under "build" folder. That means, that there is no running server on localhost on your builded electron app, so localhost will not be callable.
At this point you must call the builded static files:
const startURL = isDev ? 'http://localhost:3000' : `file://${path.join(__dirname, '../build/index.html')}`;
mainWindow.loadURL(startURL)

Here you will find a good starting Tutorial: Electron React Tutorial

How would I determine isDev, whenever I use require(electron-is-dev) I get an error saying I can’t use require and that I should instead use a dynamic import.

use import isDev from 'electron-is-dev'; not require...
read the documentation of that package here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-is-dev
